# Thread saftey on a ASPX Codebehind page

Tags: asp.net, thread-safety, c#-2.0

Okay, it's been such a long day that I am just going to look for input from experts.

Let's say I am doing this:

```
   public class ZipFiles : Page
{
    Hashtable hs;
```

to start with, meaning I have a member variable in this class.

Then I have lines I call in the OnLoad like:

```
                  ManagedFile mf = new ManagedFile(site);
                mf.ID = docID;
                mf.Load();
                hs.Add(Path.GetFileName(mf.URL), mf);
```

okay and finally I have a WriteDelegate method from DotNetZip that does this:

```
        private void WriteEntry(String filename,  Stream output)
    {
        ManagedFile value = (ManagedFile)hs[filename];
        using ( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(value.GetBinary()))
        {
            ms.WriteTo(output);
        }
    }
```

You can see that in the OnLoad I am putting all the mf objects into the hashtable with the FileName as their key (there will never be 2 of the same filenames) and then in the WriteDelegate I am popping them out to get the Byte[] array behind the MF object.

Is this a reciepe for disaster? Will the hashtables from different users on our site get mixed together and the bonds of the universe come apart?

Thanks for the help in advance! It's 5:09 PM and I am done for the day. Wife is making bisquick chicken fingers tonight for dinner. They are great, ask for the reciepe if you'd like it. Plus she's got our 2 boys (6 and 4) at home that just went back to school for the first time since LAST Monday. It'll be 2 tired boys and 1 tired Mommy when I roll in after 5:40 tonight!

Comment: In additional to the below answers.... I'll take that recipe please. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each visit page load will cause the hash table to be recreated. This isn't a recipe for disaster in terms of thread safety, but it's a recipe for disaster in terms of performance. You probably want to create a thread safe singleton to manage this hashtable.

Comment: Would it be possible to give some more details on how to pull that off? Or maybe point me at a link? I am all very new at this and it's kinda spinning in my head.

Comment: Hrmm now this page gets a list of docID(s) as a form submit input. If I made a Singleton, wouldn't those table entries just build up in the table over time, unless I cleared the ones I was done with out after I am done?

Comment: @Paul, I have no idea what your page is doing, it just seemed like you were building the same HashSet every single time. If that is not the case and each page visit needs a unique hash set then your implementation will work and will not cause any threading issues.

Answer (score 4):

You should not encounter any threading issues since your `HashTable` variable is not static.  Each page request will generate a new instance of your `ZipFiles` class with its own data.